# Can the `restrict` qualifier in C help finding bugs due to overlapping blocks?

Tags: c

After reading up on the keyword `restrict`, I am a bit confused. It appears to only give a hint to the compiler for possibilities of optimizations. But not so much to find bugs or increase the expressiveness of the language.

As all old time C programmers know, there is `memcpy()` and `memmove()`, the latter of those two promising to handle overlapping regions, the former promising not to handle it.

Now, you can write the `restrict` keyword at function arguments, in structs and just stand alone with a pointer declaration.

But I could not find any explanations, how it all is supposed to work if you have combinations of those applications in your code.

Example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SUCCESS 1
#define FAILED 0

typedef int Ret_t;

Ret_t check( Ret_t result, const char * expr, int line, const char * file )
{
    if(FAILED == result)
        printf("Expr: %s failed! (%s:%d)\n", expr, file,line);
    return result;
}


#define CHECK(expr) (check(expr,#expr))
#define CHECK_ABORT(expr) if(FAILED == check((expr),#expr,__LINE__,__FILE__)) return FAILED
#define CHECK_ABORT_MAIN(expr) if(FAILED == check((expr),#expr,__LINE__,__FILE__)) return -1
#define ARRAY_CAPACITY(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

typedef struct Slice_uint8_tag
{
    uint8_t * restrict p;
    size_t capacity;
} Slice_uint8_t;

typedef struct const_Slice_uint8_tag
{
    const uint8_t * restrict p;
    size_t size;
} const_Slice_uint8_t;

static inline
Slice_uint8_t
make_Slice_uint8 (uint8_t* restrict p,size_t capacity)
{
    Slice_uint8_t s = { .p = p, .capacity = capacity };
    return s;
}

static inline 
const_Slice_uint8_t
make_const_Slice_uint8 (const uint8_t *restrict p, size_t size)
{
    const_Slice_uint8_t s = { .p = p, .size = size };
    return s;
}

Ret_t mm(Slice_uint8_t target, const_Slice_uint8_t source)
{
    if(target.capacity >= source.size)
    {
        size_t i;
        for(i = 0; i < source.size; ++i)
        {
            target.p[i] = source.p[i];
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    return FAILED;
}

int main()
{
    const char hello[] = "Hello World!";
    unsigned char buffer[100];
    unsigned char buffer1[100];

    printf("hello array length: %ld\nlength of hello string: %ld\n", ARRAY_CAPACITY(hello), strlen(hello));

    CHECK_ABORT_MAIN(mm(make_Slice_uint8(buffer,ARRAY_CAPACITY(buffer)),make_const_Slice_uint8((const uint8_t*)hello,strlen(hello) + 1)));
    printf( "buffer after mm(): %s\n", buffer);

    CHECK_ABORT_MAIN(mm(make_Slice_uint8(buffer1,ARRAY_CAPACITY(buffer1)),make_const_Slice_uint8(buffer,ARRAY_CAPACITY(buffer))));
    printf( "buffer1 after mm(): %s\n", buffer1);

    // Now, lets see if `restrict` wins us something:
    CHECK_ABORT_MAIN(mm(make_Slice_uint8(buffer1,ARRAY_CAPACITY(buffer1)),make_const_Slice_uint8(buffer1,ARRAY_CAPACITY(buffer1))));
    printf( "buffer1 after mm(): %s\n", buffer1);
    return 0;
}
```

The members `p` in both `Slice_uint8_t` and `const_Slice_uint8_t` are marked as `restrict`ed. And now the function `mm` takes 2 instances of those structs... and this raises my question:

Can I expect the compiler to be clever and use those `restrict` adornments in such a case or are they making matters even worse (e.g. by introducing undefined behavior)?

I compiled all that with: `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -O3 -o main *.c` and it compiled with 0 warnings, 0 errors.

Comment: Pretty sure that restrict just makes it undefined and allows the compiler to do untraceable evil unto your code.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Yes, I also feared that the undefined behavior of my code tossed over a sack of rice in china each time I ran it.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/restrict-keyword-c/

Comment: I had read that keeksforgeeks.org section and my preliminary conclusion was that it is better not to use that ``restrict`` keyword at all. Unless someone here convinces me otherwise :)

Comment: restrict can allow the compiler a few optimization advantages, but you have to be damn careful when using.  To the point where it becomes a magnet during code reviews...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I expect the compiler to be clever and use those `restrict`
>   adornments in such a case or are they making matters even worse (e.g.
>   by introducing undefined behavior)?

The `restrict` qualifier serves primarily to give compilers license for optimization.  The only language *constraint* (whose violation requires a diagnostic) is that only object pointers may be `restrict`-qualified.  As a quality of implementation matter, you can hope that your compiler will diagnose violations of restrict qualification, but in practice, no compiler can guarantee to catch all violations.